# Dereferencing a pointer in a 'for' loop initializer creates a segmentation fault

Tags: c, for-loop, pointers, declaration

I'm having a problem using pointers in a `for` loop. In my `for` loop initializer, I dereference an `int` pointer and give it a value of '0'. When I use that dereferenced pointer in the loop I get a segmentation fault, and I don't understand why. I am using [Code::Blocks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code::Blocks) and the C GNU GCC compiler.

1. Looking at the watch window I can see that during the `for` loop the variable has a random number.
2. It seems that the dereferenced pointer loses scope during the `for` loop.

The code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int val = 0;
    int *p = NULL;
    int answer = 0;

    p = &val;

    *p = 1; // This dereferences and sets to one successfully

    for (int i=3, (*p)=0 ; i>=0; i--) // Here *p is a random number
    {
        printf("do stuff");
        (*p) += 1; // Here it causes a segmentation fault
    }
    answer = *p;
}
```

I thought that there would be no problems using a pointer the way I am.

Comment: Declare the `i` outside the loop and use `for(i = 3, *p=0; i >=0 ...`

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Take a close look here:

```
for (int i=3, (*p)=0 ; i>=0; i--)
```

In the first part of the `for` you're defining a **new** pointer variable named `p` which shadows the `p` defined earlier and initializing it to NULL.  You then dereference the NULL pointer in the loop which causes the segfault.

You can't have both a variable definition and an assignment to an existing variable together like that, so move the assignment of `*p` to before the loop:

```
*p = 0;
for (int i=3; i>=0; i--)
```

Or you can define `i` outside of the loop:

```
int i;
for (i=3, (*p)=0 ; i>=0; i--)
```

You *could* squeeze these together by abusing the comma operator:

```
for (int i=(*p=0,3) ; i>=0; i--)
```

Here the assignment to `p` happens as part of the initializer for `i` so it doesn't declare a new variable.  But I wouldn't recommend this as it would make your code more difficult to read and understand.

Comment: Since they used GCC, it might be worth noting that `gcc -Wshadow` would warn about this.

Answer (score 28):

You are declaring a completely new variable called `p`:

```
for (int i=3, (*p)=0 ; i>=0; i--)
```

This is the same as:

```
for (int i=3, *p=0 ; i>=0; i--)
```

So you are creating an `int i` and an `int *p`, which points to address 0. This is not the same `p` as the one defined previously. It just shadows it. So when you dereference it, you get the segfault.

Answer (score 3):

Tip: Use `-Wshadow` to get a warning when a variable shadows another one.

```
[] $ gcc main.c -Wshadow
main.c: In function ‘main’:
main.c:13:21: warning: declaration of ‘p’ shadows a previous local [-Wshadow]
   13 |     for (int i=3, (*p)=0 ; i>=0; i--) // Here *p is a random number
      |                     ^
main.c:6:10: note: shadowed declaration is here
    6 |     int *p = NULL;
      |          ^
```

https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5de37f53cf0b094d